# How to create user input in the JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I'm creating a short game in the JavaScript console, and for inspiration, I looked at google's easter egg version (if you search text adventure then press f12 you can see it). I wanted input, the only way I could figure out how to have input was by having functions:

```
console.log('Do you like chocolate ice cream?');

function yes() {
    console.log('I don't like chocolate ice cream.');
}

function no() {
    console.log('Yeah, I agree. Who even likes chocolate ice cream anyways?');
}
```

But in google's version, you can just type yes, and it returns a bunch of text, no parentheses. I tried with variables but it didn't really look nice and it turned out green. Does anybody know how to make it google's way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really do that. The closest you can get is

```js
var input = prompt("What is your name?");
console.log("Hello, " + input + "!");
```

Answer (score 9):

I looked in the javascript console of the text adventure easter egg game, and I thought: "if google can do it, it must be possible to do it". And it sure is possible.

While looking through the game, I realised that all possible inputs were variables, which probably would have made sense because if it was anything else, you would probably get an `undefined` error.

So I did a little bit of digging, on stack overflow, and I found that it's possible to listen for when a variable is called, like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'foo', {
  get: function () {
      console.log("hello world")
  }
});
```

This listens for whenever the input `foo` is called on the window and it will run the get function.
You can implement your code logic inside the `get` function whenever the input gets called.

If you also want to style to your console, you can append "%c" to the start of your console message and add your css styles as a string as an argument to the next parameter. For example:

```
console.log('%cHello World!', 'color:blue;font-size:20px;');
```

TL;DR

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'yourproperty', {
  get: function () {
      //your code logic
  }
});
```

I hope this helped. This is my first stack overflow answer. This was very fun to look into.